# Magento EE 1.13 catalog routing

Tags: catalog, cms, routing

**UPDATE**
Below is the original question, and while it's related to what the issue ends up being, it's tangential. Please see the edits starting with number 2 for more useful background information

On our site, we have some CMS pages that explain correlation between two different categories. As such, the URLs tend to be *similar* to those catalog page URLs.

- An example CMS URL:

  - "brand/category.html"
- The category which matches:

  - "category"

Is there a setting in Magento to force category route matching to be more strict?

EDIT: I should note, though it feels obvious: These are just example names

EDIT 2: If it's helpful, all catalog pages have URLs relative to root (website.com/subcat) where subcat is a child of another category. This behavior is different from the default in other Magento installs. (Note: this isn't preferred, and it's unclear as to why it's happening).

EDIT 3: After more digging, I found a quote from an [article](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/whats-wrong-with-the-new-url-keys-in-magento.html) by Fabrizio Branca on URL keys in 1.13:

> Before 1.13/1.8 any CMS page with a url-key that was also used as a category or product url-key would be evaluated first. This way you could easily replace the main categories by cms landing pages. This has changed now. Even though the CMS controller is processed first, the product and category urls will be evaluated before the routing process starts, making it much harder to display cms content in a clean way instead.

EDIT 4: Result of more research:

- "legitimate category" exists, and by default is accessible at `/a`
- "legitimate other category" exists as well, and is at `b`
- regardless of the relationship between these two categories, either can be accessed using the other as its parent (`a/b` works fine, as does `b/a`).

  - note that `a/b` shows products of **b** and `b/a` products of **a**
- **However**, `b/b` does not work, nor does `non-existant-category/a`

What I'm looking for is a URL structure similar to the previous Magento versions (IE `category/subcategory`), without losing the benefits of background indexing that 1.13 gives.

Comment: I think you will need to explain *"Is there a setting in Magento to force category route matching to be more strict"* a bit more.

Comment: Well, clearly Magento is making assumptions by matching the request `website.com/brand/category.html` to the route `website.com/category`. My question is how to make that not happen.

Comment: There is no *native* programmatic connection between SEF category URLs and CMS page URLs.

Comment: I appreciate that you're sticking with me on this, but I am not sure how to use that comment to help find a solution.

Comment: You're asking about a setting of "strictness" for category URLs, and you provide a context for this question involving CMS pages. There is no such native connection in Magento, so we'll have to know more about your question, your environment (customizations, etc.). Routes for these entities are based on data in entirely different tables, and there are separate router classes for each.

Comment: I've amended my original question to be more clear. The issue seems to be less about routing CMS vs categories and more about odd behavior in the category router wherein routes that shouldn't match are doing so.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the issue. When there is a CMS page with an identifier `foo`, and a category with a URL key `foo`, the category match is "winning" over the CMS page. Correct?

Comment: Even worse, for the request `foo/bar.html` the category with URL key `bar` has precendence over the CMS page with identifier `foo/bar.html`

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem you're trying to solve is.  There's no clear "I did X, I expected Y to happen, but Z happened instead" in your question.

Comment: I have two unrelated categories (both under the same root) with `url_key`s `foo` and `bar` and a cms page with `identifier` `foo/bar.html`. When I browse to `foo/bar.html` I expect to see the CMS page. **Instead**, I see the catalog page for `bar`. **Another note** - If another category `baz` exists, then I can add it to the URL for category bar (`foo/baz/bar.html`) and still land on the bar catalog page. However, if `baz` _does not exist_, that's a 404 page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*Thought I'd posted an answer similar to [Alan's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4350/5), but I hadn't. Sitting here in LocalStorage. But, I can tag onto his answer with an interesting solution theory.*)

The CMS router adds itself to the Front Controller instance by observing the [`controller_front_init_routers` event](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php#L147) *after* the Admin and Standard routers are added. With a little config XML, it would be possible to switch this to the [`controller_front_init_before` event](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php#L128), thereby adding the CMS router *first*, meaning its `match()`ing logic will run before the others.

To test this theory, drop the following into ***app/etc/local.xml***:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <!-- fire observer for different event -->
        <controller_front_init_before>
            <observers>
                <cms>
                    <class>Mage_Cms_Controller_Router</class>
                    <method>initControllerRouters</method>
                </cms>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_before>
        <!-- disable the original observer -->
        <controller_front_init_routers>
            <observers>
                <cms>
                    <type>disabled</type>
                </cms>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_routers>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

See if this solves the problem.

Incidentally, the CMS router will adjust the request path in the same way as the URL rewrite model.

Comment: This is excellent. While I don't think there's anything to be done about the odd new method of category routing, giving CMS pages the first chance to match goes a long way.

Comment: Just don't name any CMS page "admin" or whatever your admin frontName is :-)

Comment: Ok, Nevermind. This isn't actually working. To make sure that I'm not crazy `frontend` is properly nested as `config`->`frontend`, yes?

Comment: Yes. Ensure that it's being loaded, but you can set a breakpoint, drop a `Mage::log()` call (or echo or whatever) `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::addRouter()` to see the order in which the router classes are added.

Comment: I can only see the `addRouter` method in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front`. Regardless, the order according to the log output was: admin, standard, cms, default.

Comment: Yes, Front Controller has that method - sorry! Based on what you've stated, your config XML is not being merged; at the very least, the "disable" part of it should break any CMS page accessed through its URL path.

Comment: Damn, and I already gave you the bounty! ;)

Comment: Troubleshooting config not loading is very easy. Quick dev version: set `Mage::isDeveloperMode(true)` in ***index.php***, clear/disable config cache, and run Magento app. If you see an error, there is invalid syntax. If you don't, something is wrong with your module initialization. Deliberately break your config XML and tinker til you get it to load (and throw an error).

Comment: It's odd, the config XML is certainly loading (if it's malformed there's an immediate error), but I can't get _any_ code to run using the `controller_front_init_before` event. If the event is switched to another, such as `controller_action_layout_load_before`, I can cause the `Mage_Cms_Controller_Router::initControllerRouters` method to fail, but I can't even test functions to run on `controller_front_init_before`.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that - the `controller_front_init_before` event fires well before the event areas are loaded. So sorry. Use `<global>` instead of `<frontend>`. Damn. Really sorry! I point this out all the time in my classes too. *gulp*

Answer (score 6):

I've seen a lot of interesting implementations (some good, some bad) by SEO specialists who didn't have a Magento background throughout the years.  It sounds like you may be running into problems with some custom code you don't understand.  The high level answer to your question may be "Contact the person who wrote the SEO code and/or installed the extension you don't understand", or find a Magento consultant to take a look and quickly dissect it for you.

Your question, even with its clarification, is still too confusing.  Literally speaking, no, there's no setting in Magento to "force category routing to be more strict".   I'm going to explain, in broad terms, how category routing works vs. CMS routing in a standard Magento system. This will (hopefully) give you enough information to ask a new question in terms we'll be able to understand it by.  Also, I've written extensively on Magento's request dispatch before, so if you're interested on the nitty gritty details I'd [start there](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#dispatch).

### Category Routing

There is, strictly speaking, no "category" routing in Magento.  On a site with SEO Friendly URLs turned off, a category listing page looks like this.

```
http://magento.example.com/catalog/category/view/id/8
```

When SEO friendly URLs are on, Magento (in an indexing process) creates between one and several entries in the

```
core_url_rewrite
```

table for that category.  The `request_path` column is the import one here.  When Magento is deciding how to handle a particular URL, it will first look in this table.  If the current URL matches the `request_path`, Magento will **change** its internal representation of the URL so it look like the `target_path` column.

So, in the sample data, there's a row that looks like this

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
url_rewrite_id: 17
      store_id: 1
   category_id: 8
    product_id: NULL
       id_path: category/8
  request_path: electronics/cell-phones.html
   target_path: catalog/category/view/id/8
     is_system: 1
       options: NULL
   description: NULL
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

When Magento sees the url `http://magento.example.com/electronics/cell-phones.html`, it matches this row because the `request_path` variable is `electronics/cell-phones.html`.  It then changes its internal representation of the URL to the `target_path` (`catalog/category/view/id/8`).  Then, Magento handles the URL normally.

That's probably a bit much to follow if you're not used to it, but the important thing to take away is **the system that decides how to handle the URL doesn't care that it's a category URL, it just cares that there's an entry in the `core_url_rewrite` table**.  This same table is used for product name URLs.  Many SEO extensions and custom code solution use this table as well.

### CMS Page Routing

After Magento finishes referencing the `core_url_rewrite` table, what happens next is

1. It checks for any Admin application page matches (manage products, manage categories, etc.)
2. It checks for any Frontend application page matches (product listing page, the above mentioned category listing page, etc.)
3. If numbers 1 & 2 contain no matches, it then looks for a CMS page match.

Magento **doesn't** use the `core_url_rewrite` table for CMS pages.  Instead, if is reaches step number 3, it tries to match the URL with the `URL Key` set on the CMS page object.  (it would be more accurate to say that when Magento is looking for a CMS page match, it's operating on a URL already modified by the `core_url_rewrite` process — but things are already confusing enough)

The important take aways here is: CMS matching happens only after a category page match has failed.

It sounds like you may have external processes modifying the `core_url_rewrite` table, or may have a custom router object added to your system the does extra routing, or maybe even a non-magento system doing things to change URLs.

I'm afraid there's no quick and easy answer for your situation.

Comment: I may have a solution, see [my answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4315/router-fuzzy-catalog-match-vs-exact-cms-match/4351#4351)

Comment: I don't believe that any custom code is affecting the category URL rewriting (though I'll be taking a hard look at the `core_url_rewrite` table). From the very start of development, I can recall that `subcategory` would match `/subcategory.html` (as opposed to `category/subcategory.html`) -- even before any outside code was brought in. (`\n`) Suppose this could've been useful earlier on, but is it possible that there was a change in EE 1.13 that could be causing this?

Comment: @mpw I don't know.  My approach is debug these things from the bottom up.

Comment: Just checked the `core_url_rewrite` table. It's empty. Could [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-indexing#ee113-11301-url-key) have anything to do with my issues?

Comment: Updated my question again, there's some interesting behavior in EE 1.13 (unmodified, using sample data).

Comment: As far as I can tell, core_url_rewrite is not used in 1.13, though I'm not sure about that. I think that only enterprise_url_rewrite is used now.

Answer (score 6):

@benmarks answer is already good. But you will still have issues if your product URLs match your CMS page URLs. The URL rewrites from the table `core_url_rewrite` are checked before the routers are checked - see `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::dispatch`:

```
public function dispatch()
{
    // [...]
    $this->_getRequestRewriteController()->rewrite();

    Varien_Profiler::start('mage::dispatch::routers_match');
    $i = 0;
    while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++ < 100) {
        foreach ($this->_routers as $router) {
            /** @var $router Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract */
            if ($router->match($request)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // [...]
}
```

If a product URL matches the current path info, the path info of the request will be changed in `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request::_rewriteDb`, so that the CMS router will not match any more even though it is called before the catalog router (if you applied @benmarks config.xml).

Fortunately, there is a nice flag called `straight`, which can be set on a `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http`. If the flag is set, the URL rewrites from the database will not be checked. Hence, my solution is to observe an event, which is fired early enough (`controller_front_init_before`) and set the `straight` flag on the request in it if the current path info matches a CMS page identifier:

In your config.xml:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_front_init_before>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>controllerFrontInitBefore</method>
                </namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_before>
    </events>
<global>
```

Your observer method:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{

    public function controllerFrontInitBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http $request */
        $request = $observer->getFront()->getRequest();

        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $pageId = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->checkIdentifier($identifier, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

        if ($pageId) {
            $request->isStraight(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Since the catalog router will not match if the the database URL rewrites are not applied, this solution should work on its own and you do not even need the config.xml of @benmarks.

Hope this helps someone - that took quite some effort to debug!

Comment: Very nice find.

Answer (score 5):

> What I'm looking for is a URL structure similar to the previous Magento versions (IE category/subcategory), without losing the benefits of background indexing that 1.13 gives.

This is a problem I've been looking at, which so far doesn't seem to have a great solution. We have some deeply nested categories, for example:

```
Cat A
    Cat B
        Cat C
            Cat D
```

Prior to 1.13, the category url would have generated as www.domain.com/cat-a/cat-b/cat-c/cat-d/, but now it generates as www.domain.com/catd. Although if you have multiple "Cat D"s, then it could generate as something like www.domain.com/catalog/category/view/s/cat-d/id/132/.

I've been tinkering with different ideas for addressing this, one thing I'm trying right now is to modify the loadByRequestPath method of Enterprise_UrlRewrite_Model_Resource_Url_Rewrite to first look for a full path, before using the default behavior. I did that by adding this method:

```
protected function tryLoadByFullPath($object, $paths)
{
    if (count($paths) > 1) {
        $_path = implode('/', $paths);

        $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
            ->from(array('m' => $this->getMainTable()))
            ->where('m.request_path = ?', $_path);

        $result = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchRow($select);

        if ($result) {
            $object->setData($result);
            $this->unserializeFields($object);
            $this->_afterLoad($object);

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and then adding this code to the top of loadByRequestPath():

```
if ($this->tryLoadByFullPath($object, $paths)) {
        return $this;
}
```

It appears to work, at first glance anyway, I haven't tested it very well yet. The downside to this is that the url_key has to be manually set to the full path for every category, so you would have to set the url key for Cat D to "cat-a/cat-b/cat-c/cat-d". That's obviously not ideal.

Anyway, that's probably not very helpful, but maybe someone has a better take on this approach.

Comment: Just glad to not be alone in this! If we find a solution, I'll be sure to report it.